# If $4x^2+y^2=40$ and $xy=-6$, find the value of $2x+y$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $4x^2+y^2=40$ and $xy=-6$, find the value of $2x+y$.

I tried the following,

As we know, $(a+b)^2=a^2+b^2+2ab$

Therefore, $(4x^2+y^2)^2=(4x^2)^2+(y^2)+2(4x^2*y^2)$

$=16^4+y^4+8x^2y^2$

What should I do know? Please help. I am stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$(2x+y)^2=4x^2+4xy+y^2=(4x^2+y^2)+4xy=40+4(-6)=16 \Rightarrow 2x+y=\pm 4$$

Comment: Thank you! I just wanted to know that why you wrote +- 4? How did you find it?

Comment: @Abhishekstudent Because,we know that if $x^2=a, a>0$,then $x=\pm \sqrt{a}$.

Comment: Thank you! You have helped me a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$(2x+y)^2-4xy=4x^2+y^2$

You can take it from here?